# Get Difference between 2 array of objects using class validator

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, class-validator

I have object array, and I want to get the difference which doesn't exists in the second array.

I am already achieving this like and its providing the result I am expecting:

```js
const arr1 = [
  { "id": "1" },
  { "id": "4" },
  { "id": "7" }, 
  { "id": "5" }
]

const arr2 = [
  { "id": "1" },
  { "id": "5" }
]

const result = arr1.filter(item => !arr2.some(other => item.id == other.id));

console.log(result);
```

The point here is that I want to achieve this using class-validator:

> https://github.com/typestack/class-validator

Is there any way I can get same result using this library?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What exactly you want to achieve? Are duplicates supposed to be invalid?

Comment: @Wimanicesir if arr2 doesnt not have exact ids as arr1, I need to validate and need to return the missing ids

Comment: @Wimanicesir you can check my jsfiddle for the result I am expecting